# In PHP, how to replace GET method by using Sessions or POST method?

Tags: php, session, post, get

Below is the table where the "View Details" link holds the values of "Head of Account", "Financial Year" & "Budget" in url:

**Page 1**

[image]

After clicking on the link "View Details", a new page will be displayed as:

**Page 2**

[image: image of page2]

I have achieved it using GET method ( the database hold the value of "View Details"),so that every time appropriate page is displayed after clicking the "View Details" button.

I would like to know if the same could be achieved using POST method or SESSIONS. If Yes, then how?

Comment: Question: why? What problem are you trying to solve? Regardless, yes, it can be done. You could simply create a form that you post with the information instead of having an ordinary link. Then you should either create one form per row which you submit when the user clicks "view" or you can have one form, which you, through JS set the correct record and submit when a user clicks "view".

Comment: would you like to post code?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah You can use the POST but I don't think you can use the SESSIONS for these. In order to use the POST method, you'll have to convert each link into a mini form and post it to an action. Consider the code below:

```
<form id="postlink" method="post" action="view.php">
    <input name="postId" type="hidden" />
    <button type="submit" style="display:none;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then you'll have to include a common class to the links and some jQuery code.

```
// $i refers to the primary key of the entry that is got while looping the data.
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="post_link" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>">View</a>
jQuery(".post_link").click(function () {
    jQuery("form#postlink input[name='postId']").val(jQuery(this).attr('data-id'));
    jQuery("form#postlink").submit();
});
```

But this is the long way and nobody prefers this method since there is so much code involved. The best method is to use the GET method as this is used to SELECT the data. If you are concerned about security issues then you can encrypt the Primary key that is passed in the link and in the corresponding file you can decrypt that primary key.

Hope this helps.